# boost is unable to read ^A character

Tags: c++, vim, boost

I have an xml file generated by boost library (using write_xml). When I try to read it using boost's read_xml function, it gives me an error saying

**< unspecified file>(20):expected <**

when I open the file through vim, correctly written xml tags are ended at 19th line and it shows an additional ^A character at line 20.

This happens in Mac 10.6 xcode 3.2.2 x64 environment.

what does ^A mean?

how could I get rid of this ^A character.

Comment: Sounds like you are using UTF-16 instead of UTF-8.

Comment: @romain I disagree. ^A is a CR, as rendered by vim. So that's a line endings thing. But XML should be line ending agnostic so I suspect that's a red herring. The OP needs to post _actual_ XML and _actual_ error messages.

Comment: In Unix, CR is rendered as ^M. It may be due to fileformat setting as well.